# Command 'pytest' not found even though I moved pytest.py to /bin

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

On Ubuntu 18.04-x64 I need to install the Pytest library for Python.

I ran the following commands:

```
pip3 install pytest
pytest --version
```

I get the following error:

```
Command 'pytest' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install python-pytest
```

However, when I run:

```
pip3 show pytest
```

I get:

```
Name: pytest
Version: 4.3.1
...
Location: /home/crispjam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

I decided to move the `pytest.py` file from its location in `site-packages` to `/bin` but that did not solve my problem.

When I run:

```
pytest --version
```

I still get:

```
 Command 'pytest' not found, but can be installed with:
 sudo apt install python-pytest
```

Is this not the right way of doing things? Should I instead be concerned with editing `$PATH`?

EDIT: I also tried installing `pytest` with `sudo apt install python-pytest` but that installed an outdated version - `3.3.2` which I cannot use for my project.

Comment: No, it's not the right way, put it back. Does `python3 -m pytest` work? That's the recommended way to ensure using the right python for a given library.

Comment: They installed with pip. You're recommending apt-get update. Hmm...?

Comment: run `find /home/crispjam -name pytest -type f` and when you find the path to pytest include it in your PATH with something like `export PATH=$PATH:/home/crispjam/.local/bin/` (replace with the path you found in the previous command).

Comment: yeah  try @PauloScardine  solution . It has got to do with $PATH configuration

Comment: @Andras Deak `python3 -m pytest` works.  How would I then transfer this pytest call: `pytest ./ -v -s -m [some_marked_test]`?

Comment: Replace `pytest` with `python3 -m pytest`, it should work.